Cannot run program "python3": CreateProcess error=2, Le fichier spécifié est introuvable
Igot this error :
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[5], line 53
     43 expanded_df = parsed_df.select(
     44     "RECID",
     45     "OPDATE_AGC",
   (...)
     49     # Add more fields as needed
     50 )
     52 # Show the resulting DataFrame
---> 53 expanded_df.show(truncate=False)
     55 # Save the result to a CSV file
     56 expanded_df.write.csv("output/extracted_data.csv", header=True, mode='overwrite')

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o133.showString.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 3.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 3.0 (TID 3) (PC-3E-HC-87.Qmb.Root.local executor driver): java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "python3": CreateProcess error=2, Le fichier spécifié est introuvable


while exuting this script
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, StringType
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import os
import sys

os.environ['PYSPARK_PYTHON'] = sys.executable
os.environ['PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON'] = sys.executable

# Define a schema for the UDF output
schema = StructType([
    StructField("c1", StringType(), True),
    StructField("c2", StringType(), True),
    # Add more fields as needed
])

# Define a UDF to parse XML and extract data
def extract_from_xml(xml_string):
    try:
        root = ET.fromstring(xml_string)
        data = {
            "c1": root.find('c1').text if root.find('c1') is not None else None,
            "c2": root.find('c2').text if root.find('c2') is not None else None,
            # Add more fields as needed
        }
        return (data["c1"], data["c2"])  # Return a tuple matching the schema
    except ET.ParseError:
        return (None, None)  # Return None for all fields on error

# Register the UDF with the specified schema
extract_udf = F.udf(extract_from_xml, schema)

# Apply the UDF to the XMLRECORD column
parsed_df = df.select(
    "RECID",
    "OPDATE_AGC",
    "UPDATE_AGC",
    extract_udf(df.XMLRECORD).alias("parsed_data")
)

# Expand the parsed data into separate columns
expanded_df = parsed_df.select(
    "RECID",
    "OPDATE_AGC",
    "UPDATE_AGC",
    F.col("parsed_data.c1").alias("c1"),
    F.col("parsed_data.c2").alias("c2"),
    # Add more fields as needed
)

# Show the resulting DataFrame
expanded_df.show(truncate=False)

# Save the result to a CSV file
expanded_df.write.csv("output/extracted_data.csv", header=True, mode='overwrite')

Issue:
The error suggests that Spark is trying to call python3, which is not recognized on my Windows system (I can only use python).
Questions:
How can I ensure that PySpark uses the correct Python executable?
Is there a way to specify the Python version for PySpark on Windows?
Additional Information:
I’m running this code on a Windows machine.
The installed version of Python is 3.12.6.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!
